# CSS position relative and absolute

Tags: html, css, css-position

I am new to web development. I have some doubt related to positioning of elements.

When i run the below code the black background element is inside the red background element.

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
 <title></title>
</head>
<body>
 <div style="position: absolute;left:100px;top: 100px;height:600px;background-color: yellow;width: 600px;">
  <div style="position:relative;left:100px;top:100px;height:200px;width:500px;background-color: red;">
  </div>
  <div style="position:relative;left:100px;top:50px;height:10px;width:10px;background-color: black;">
  </div>
 </div>
</body>
</html>
```

But if I make position of red rectangle to be absolute then black rectangle moves to the correct positioning maintaining the correct left and top from its parent(yellow rectangle). Can anyone tell me why is it like that? How can I make the black rectangle to correctly position itself from its parent(yellow rectangle) even if the position of red rectangle is relative.

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`relative` positioning keeps elements on the page so their position is affected by other `static` and `relative` positioned elements. If you want the black box to be positioned relative to the yellow box, you want to make the black box `position: absolute`. An `absolute`ly positioned element will be positioned relative to it's closest non-`static` positioned ancestor.

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
  <title></title>
</head>

<body>
  <div style="position: absolute;left:100px;top: 100px;height:600px;background-color: yellow;width: 600px;">
    <div style="position:relative;left:100px;top:100px;height:200px;width:500px;background-color: red;">
    </div>
    <div style="position:absolute;left:100px;top:50px;height:10px;width:10px;background-color: black;">
    </div>
  </div>
</body>

</html>
```